# How to Remove Stop Words from a string using Visual Basic?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking to find a way to remove stop words using a function in Visual Basic inside my Access DB.

Today I'm just doing several replace but I know it's not the right way as I wouldn't know if I'm removing the Stop Word as a word or within a word.

Any help would be great, I just cannot find any way to do this on VB.

Comment: Do you mean VBA, ie used with MS Access. How about including spaces, for example "* in *"? It will miss start and end wprds, but may be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you mean something like this, right?

```
OutputString = Replace("They answered the question", "the", "")
```

This replaces all occurrences of "the" from the phrase, including part of the word "They".

The simplest solution would be to put spaces before and after the word to replace:

```
OutputString = Replace("They answered the question", " the ", "")
```

This works for the phrase in my above example, but it won't work when the word occurs at the beginning or at the end of the phrase.
For these cases, you need to do more. Something like this:

```
Public Function RemoveStopWords( _
                                ByVal Phrase As String, _
                                ByVal WordToRemove As String _
                                ) As String

    Dim RetVal As String
    Dim Tmp As String

    'remove the word in the middle of the phrase
    RetVal = Replace(Phrase, " " & WordToRemove & " ", " ")

    'remove the word at the beginning
    Tmp = WordToRemove & " "
    If Left(RetVal, Len(Tmp)) = Tmp Then
        RetVal = Mid(RetVal, Len(Tmp) + 1)
    End If

    'remove the word at the end
    Tmp = " " & WordToRemove
    If Right(RetVal, Len(Tmp)) = Tmp Then
        RetVal = Left(RetVal, Len(RetVal) - Len(Tmp))
    End If

    RemoveStopWords = RetVal

End Function
```

This works as long as the words in the phrase are always separated with blanks.
When there can be other separators than blanks, you have to do even more.

For example, instead of hardcoding the blanks in the function, you could loop over a list of separators and execute the function for each one.
I won't show this as code now, but you get the idea.

Comment: Wow you seriously understand my question and I thank you for answering. Since I have many stopwords, I will do a while loop to make this function go over an array!

Comment: @user1238765: Glad to help. If my answer was helpful to you, it would be nice if you [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it!